# Java Image4j: method not return when decoding ico image

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, ico

I'm trying to use image4j 0.7 library to decode .ico file.
My code is here:

```
    //File address
    String sourceAddress="/home/tojandro/Desktop/favicon.ico";

    //Read data
    InputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(sourceAddress);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer=new byte[0xfff];
    int length=-1;
    while( (length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0 )
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();
    ByteArrayInputStream dataBuffer=new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

    //Try to decode
    System.out.println("Decode begin.");
    ICODecoder.read(dataBuffer);                        //This method could never been return.
    //ICODecoder.read(new File(sourceAddress));         //This method works well.
    System.out.println("Decode finished.");
```

My problem is: 
   When I decode image from file directly, the method works well;
   But when I decode image from byte buffer, sometimes(some files ok and some files not) the method would never return.

Anybody could help me? Thanks.

Comment: I thought `favicon.ico` where png files? (Assuming this is a web favicon...)

Comment: Why not pass it the original/source `InputStream`?

Comment: Can you link to a problem file (that doesn't decode)

Comment: Here is the file, http://www.digu.com/favicon.ico

Comment: I use linux file command to check the file, and result is: "/home/tojandro/Desktop/favicon.ico: MS Windows icon resource - 1 icon"

Comment: I confirm the problem, I can't provide a solution, it might be data conversion issue when read the data in from the original stream...

Comment: Use origin stream is ok. ICODecoder.read(new FileInputStream(sourceAddress)); But I still don't know why it not works with my buffer. it doesn't throw exception , does not return empty or null, just block the thread and not return -_-......

Comment: It gets trapped in a loop where it tries to skip some bytes, but can't because the calculation results in it skipping `0` bytes...

Comment: I figure it out by adding: outputStream.write(new byte[0x80]);
  outputStream.flush();